# Accessing the Row Height in Dynamic UITableView Prototypes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

OK. There's a number of questions that touch on this, but none that actually address what I need.

What I need, quite simply, is to get the value that I set in IB for the "custom row height" of a DYNAMIC (not static) table cell prototype.

If the table sets up static prototypes, then this is automatically honored. However, when using dynamic prototypes, this value is ignored in favor of the table's main rowHeight value.

I'd like to be able to access this value, so I can return it in the `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` method. I can do this manually, by having an internal table of heights, and matching to the prototype, but that's messy and awkward, and requires that the prototype always appear in a certain row.

When `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` is called, I can synthesize the reuseID, but I'd like to avoid having to load the viewcell until the proper time (`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`).

Is there a good way to access this? I don't see any literature in the Apple docs about accessing prototypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Ok, I see what is your problem. In iOS development, we deal with tasks like this with different subclasses of UITableCell. Like this:

```
+ (CGFloat)layoutHeightWithEntity:(id)entity {
    CGFloat layoutHeight = 0;
    // use data to calculate layout height dynamically if needed
    // id data = [entity data];
    // layoutHeight = layoutHeight + [data ...];

    // or use a static layout height if the height of this kind of cells do not change
    layoutHeight = 100;

    return layoutHeight;
}
```

And in your view controller, you need to prepare data source for your table view like this:

```
NSMutableArray *dataList = [NSMutableArray new];

NSMutableArray *firstSection = [NSMutableArray new];
[firstSection addObject:[XXXTableEntity entityWithReuseCellID:@"nameCell" data:someData cellClass:[XXXNameCell class]];
[dataList addObject:firstSection];

NSMutableArray *secondSection = [NSMutableArray new];
[firstSection addObject:[XXXTableEntity entityWithReuseCellID:@"pickerCell" data:someData cellClass:[XXXPickerCell class]];
[dataList addObject:secondSection];

[self setDataList:dataList];
```

your `CustomTableEntity` may look like this:

```
+ (instancetype)entityWithEntityID:(NSString *)entityID
                       cellReUseID:(NSString *)cellReUseID
                         cellClass:(Class<XXXBaseTableCellLayout>)cellClass
                        dataEntity:(id)dataEntity
                precalculateHeight:(BOOL)precalculateHeight {

    XXXBaseTableCellEntity *entity = [self new];

    [entity setEntityID:entityID];
    [entity setReuseCellID:cellReUseID];
    [entity setDataEntity:dataEntity];

    [entity setCellClass:cellClass];

    if (precalculateHeight) {
        [entity setLayoutHeight:[cellClass layoutHeightWithEntity:dataEntity]];
    }

    return entity;
}

- (CGFloat)layoutHeight {
    if (_layoutHeight > 0) {

        return _layoutHeight;
    }

    _layoutHeight = [[self cellClass] layoutHeightWithEntity:[self dataEntity]];

    return _layoutHeight;
}
```

then in your UITableViewDataSource methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return self.dataList.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.dataList[section] count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return [[[[self dataList] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] layoutHeight];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    XXXTableEntity *entity = [[[self dataList] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    XXXBaseTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[entity reuseCellID] forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell configureWithEntity:entity];

    return cell;
}
```

the code above are basically from a framework I write for my company, but you should get the idea. The framework has 3 classes related to table view: `XXXBaseTableCell`, `XXXBaseTableViewController`, `XXXBaseTableCellEntity`. All view controllers contains a table view subclass `XXXBaseTableViewController`, all table cells subclass `XXXBaseTableCell`, all table entities subclass `XXXBaseTableCellEntity`.

---

May I ask you why you want to do this? I think you are having some problems with table view. If you can explain why you want to do it, maybe I can help you so that you don't need to do it at all.

You cannot access the height of prototype cells in the standard approach. But actually you can access any data in a storyboard file if you really want to do it. Below is how:

Storyboard is a XML file. Everything you do when you are editing a storyboard file in IB are encoded in a XML file. You can access any information you need by parsing XML file yourself. You can read the XML data in a storyboard file and feed it to a XML parser to get the DOM data. Then you can query the DOM to get data. Here is the XML view of a test storyboard which contains a table view controller:

```
    <!--Table View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="hbL-mT-mfb">
        <objects>
            <tableViewController id="XNl-aA-YKn" customClass="TableViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" id="lX1-Ry-xNl">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <prototypes>
                        <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="cell" rowHeight="100" id="4rn-ee-JoI">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="375" height="100"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="4rn-ee-JoI" id="bdN-kI-rps">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="99"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                            </tableViewCellContentView>
                        </tableViewCell>
                    </prototypes>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="dataSource" destination="XNl-aA-YKn" id="GlZ-SO-7gG"/>
                        <outlet property="delegate" destination="XNl-aA-YKn" id="gqq-QI-tZD"/>
                    </connections>
                </tableView>
            </tableViewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="RCX-w1-742" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="118" y="798"/>
    </scene>
```

Please don't do it this way...

Comment: Don't worry. I won't do it that way. What I am doing, is using a tableview to manage the display of a long series of various control panels. Each one is a table row with a different set of controls. For example, a name might be a simple UITextField, but a weekday might be a UIPickerView. Thus, each one is different, and may contain vastly different controls. I have it set up so each row has an associated class, with handlers for the controls for that item. I would use my "table of heights" before using the XML parser thing.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the complete and well-written response. I'll greencheck it, although there's no guarantee I'll use it until I've had a chance to study it and compare it against my use case. At first blush, it seems to be a bit more complex than my approach, but I may be able to figure out how to apply it. The basic deal is that I want to simplify the process of describing these various panels. In my previous app, I had separate .xib files that I instantiated along with a set of heights. That was way too involved for me.

Comment: @MAGNAWS sure. But I want to say that, your "internal table of heights" and my setup are the same thing in nature. Think about it, table view needs to know layout information to render your content. No matter how you provide a table view layout info, you are really building a render tree like data structure and feeding it to your table view. My setup is a more general purpose and abstracted effort, your "internal table of heights" is a more quick and hard-coded approach. In fact, hard coding heights in storyboard is the same thing. The only problem is that you can't fetch your built tree from

Comment: a storyboard file in the standard way. sorry, English is not my first language. I hope you can understand what Im trying to express here.

Comment: Exactly. You are correct in comparing the two. Essentially the same. If you are interested, [here's the code for what I'm working on](https://bitbucket.org/bmlt/na-meeting-list-administrator/src/master/NA%20Meeting%20List%20Administrator/View%20Controllers/MeetingEditorBaseViewController.swift?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default). It's an open-source project; still quite a lot needs to be done, and you can't easily test it without logging into the server, but you can see what I'm doing. I'm assigning a class to each panel, and using their reuseIDs as keys.

Comment: @MAGNAWS I've checked your project. Your approach should work if your cells are all static. For static I mean they are cells that may contain a input control like a picker or text field, these cells have same layout height when they are reused in different sections. But be careful when using this technique in a dynamic table view. Because a cell can be reused in different sections and may have variable layout heights. Basically, the idea of addressing this kind of tasks in iOS programming is that preparing rendering data, which includes layout and actual data, your view components needed.

Comment: @MAGNAWS When you are configuring a table view in a storyboard file, you are actually building a render tree the table view will use in runtime. But unfortunately, you can only fetch parts of information in the render tree you have built in current storyboard or xib related API. I understand you want to get the whole information you have put into in a storyboard file, but you can't. So you have to rebuild the whole render tree in code. You can do this in a quick manner like in your project, or you can solve this with a complete solution like I did in my answer

Comment: Thanks. You are correct about the static thing. The reason that I chose dynamic, is because it is not possible to intercept the creation event of static cells, and I need that in order to apply some runtime information. I've decided that my approach will work. It isn't perfect, but it's relatively simple. I'm giving a priority to make the app as being something that can be fairly easily modded and localized. This is an approach that has paid dividends in the past. I really appreciate your feedback.